# My Android application restarts after screensaver appears

Tags: android

Everytime after couple minutes of idle state, screensaver appears on my phone. It makes my Android application restart. Do you know how to overcome this? Of course, I know I could turn off the screensaver, but it's not the solution I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by restarts? What do you mean by screensaver? If I understood your question correctly you must check if you have this line in your AndroidManifest.xml:

> android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"

This will prevent your activity from being restarted on runtime 'configuration changes'.